# Is there a way I can get actual date?

Tags: php

I have a variable that outputs the date in the following format:
`Thursday, 01-Jan-70`
I am using this to retrieve the date but it is getting the wrong date according to the date I select
I want to get actual date
 I am trying to Post date in my input field...

```
$dateValue = isset($_POST['dateSend']); 
$day = date('D, d-M-y', strtotime($dateValue));
```

Any idea of how I can do it?

Comment: `date('l')` for full day name, `date('D')` for short day name. See [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Comment: `$dateValue` is true or false. That wont work. `isset` returns boolean. Maybe you want `$day = date('D, d-M-y', strtotime(isset($_POST['dateSend']) ? $_POST['dateSend'] : 'No date condition'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and share your feedback plz

```
if(isset($_POST['dateSend'])){
    $dateValue = $_POST['dateSend']; 
    $day = date('l, d-M-y', strtotime($dateValue ));
}
```

Comment: If I was to echo $day outside the if statement how would I do it?

Comment: if(isset($_POST With this you are telling your code to print the result of $day only if $dateValue is set (different than null). You can put an echo outside and nothing will happen since its value will be null, unless you give $day another value outside of the if statement